# Check TinyMCE content editor and remove bottom newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm working with the TinyMCE editor. I'm trying to remove an empty tag when the user submits content via an Ajax request. The TinyMCE editor preserves empty tags if the user doesn't insert content in the editor area.

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

How can I check if the editor has no content via jQuery? Furthermore, I want to remove empty tags present at the end of the content editor: for example when the user inserts a newline at the bottom, because TinyMCE translate newlines into:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

It is also possible in TinyMCE to convert newlines:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

into

```
<div class="custom_empty"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regular form and submit in this case, but get the tinymce editor content using the `ed.getContent()` - tinymce API function when a special submit button gets pushed.
You then have the chance to cleanup your tinymce editor content by yourself.

Here is some example code i use to do some character replacements due to the fact that we had to use an own font and replace some special chars when they are inside the editor:

```
content = content.replace(/\u2192/g, '\t').replace(/\u00a0/g, '\u0020').replace(/\u202F/g, '\u00a0').replace(/\u2007/g, '\u2005').replace( new RegExp("\ufeff", "g"), "").replace(/\u00ad/g, '');
```

In your use case you might consider using a regex to detect empty tags (or tags with a &bnsp ) and replace them with an empty sting.